# float left makes my box jump down

Tags: html, css

I would like put the red box(Block E) below Block C and next to Block D, and at the same time move BLOCK C up with 1% margin between the block A and itself. I've tried with different strategies but never been able to solve the problem. 
[image]

Here's my code:

```css
.newsblockContainer {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 89.2%;
  margin-left: 4vw;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  height: 73.3vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blockA {
  width: 59%;
  height: 27vw;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.blockB {
  width: 38%;
  height: 34vw;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.blockC {
  width: 59%;
  height: 23vw;
  margin-left: 1%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
  margin-top: -9.45%;
  position: relative;
}

.blockD {
  height: 36.7vw;
  width: 38%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  position: relative;
}

.blockE {
  height: 15vw;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 59%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsblockContainer">
  <div class="blockA">
    block A
  </div>
  <div class="blockB">
    block B
  </div>
  <div class="blockC">
    block C
  </div>
  <div class="blockD">
    block D
  </div>
  <div class="blockE">
    block E
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j8hg3hf1/1/

Comment: The code snippet is wrong, be sure to check fiddle instead :/

Comment: If the code snippet is wrong, then please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning instead of relative positioning for the ones you need to move. You 'll need include attributes for the  location in px, %, etc.

Edit:
You can keep the relative positioning and utilize the top attribute. The 1% margin thing may be slightly tricky this way but it can surely approximate it.

```
.blockE{
height: 15vw;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
top: 308px;
margin-top: 1%;
width: 59%;
margin-left: 1%;
```

}

This along with changing the .blockC  to top: -10px changes the image to this.

Here's a link to how the image appears
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXICM.png

Comment: Provide more detail, or show how you would implement this in their code, your answer isn't useful without more context.

Comment: Not really sure how recommending attributes and units is not useful but regardless I'll further demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It worked. If you need modification, please comment.

```css
.newsblockContainer {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 89.2%;
  margin-left: 4vw;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  height: 73.3vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blockA {
  width: 59%;
  height: 27vw;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
}

.blockB {
  width: 38%;
  height: 34vw;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  float: right;
}

.blockC {
  width: 59%;
  height: 23vw;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

.blockD {
  height: 36.7vw;
  width: 38%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  position: relative;
}

.blockE {
  height: 15vw;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 59%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsblockContainer">
  <div class="blockA">A</div>
  <div class="blockB">B</div>
  <div class="blockC">C</div>
  <div class="blockD">D</div>
  <div class="blockE">E</div>
</div>
```